# Is it possible to add custom metadata to a Lucene field?

Tags: lucene, metadata, lucene.net

I've come to the point where I need to store some additional data about where a particular field comes from in my Lucene.Net index. Specifically, I want to attach a guid to certain fields of a document when the field is added to the document, and retrieve it again when I get the document from a search result.

Is this possible?

**Edit:**
Okay, let me clarify a bit by giving an example.

Let's say I have an object that I want to allow the user to tag with custom tags like "personal", "favorite", "some-project". I do this by adding multiple "tag" fields to the document, like so:

```
doc.Add( new Field( "tag", "personal" ) );
doc.Add( new Field( "tag", "favorite" ) );
```

The problem is I now need to record some meta data about each individual tag itself, specifically a guid representing where that tag came from (imagine it as a user id). Each tag could potentially have a different guid, so I can't simply create a "tag-guid" field (*unless* the order of the values is preserved---see edit 2 below). I don't need this metadata to be indexed (and in fact I'd prefer it not to be, to avoid getting hits on metadata), I just need to be able to retrieve it again from the document/field.

```
doc.GetFields( "tag" )[0].Metadata...
```

(I'm making up syntax here, but I hope my point is clear now.)

**Edit 2:**
*Since this is a completely different question, I've posted a new question for this approach: [Is the order of multi-valued fields in Lucene stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951215/is-the-order-of-multi-valued-fields-in-lucene-stable)*

Okay let's try another approach... The key problem area is the indeterminacy of the multiple field values under the same field name (e.g. "tag"). If I could introduce or obtain some kind of determinacy here, I might be able to store the metadata in another field.

For example, if I could rely on the order of the values of the field never changing, I could use an index in the set of values to identify exactly which tag I am referring to.

Is there any guarantee that the order I add the values to a field will remain the same when I retrieve the document at a later time?

Comment: could you just add it to your document: document.Add(new Field("GUID", "guidvalue", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));

Comment: @Prescott the problem is I am adding multiple values for the same field (e.g. "tag"), and I need to keep track of certain origin information for each tag, so I have no way of just adding a new field to track it because I can't identify them uniquely.

Comment: @chaiguy I'm having some trouble fully understanding what you mean - could you toss out a super simple example?

Comment: @chaiguy Prescott is right you can add multiple fields to document only for storing - it is a common practice

Comment: trying to clarify here: Assume the following definition Document { DocId, Text, Author, CreatedDate }. Are you saying that you'd like to also add additional data to individual fields. In this case suppose, you want to tag Author with a GUID so add a new field AuthorGUID for this document?

Comment: @chaiguy - Just curious, whats your use case for adding metadata to metadata? Intuitively, I wouldn't think of tagging individual fields, but the document as a whole

Comment: See updated question--I can't just add a new field because fields support multiple values and I need metadata for *each* value in a single field.

Comment: I suppose perhaps I could simply append it to the value somehow, but would this mess up the indexing/searching? For example, if I used new Field( "tag", "favorite|metadata" )... ?

Comment: hmm, how about something like new Field("tags", "personal|date favoriate|date") some what using Xodarap's idea of payloads below?

Comment: @chaiguy - yes that *would* but using Xodarap's link to payloads you can make sure it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your search requirements for this index, this may be possible. That way you can control the order of fields. It would require updating both fields as the tag list changes of course, but the overhead may be worth it.

```
doc.Add(new Field("tags", "{personal}|{favorite}")); 
doc.Add(new Field("tagsref", "{1234}|{12345}"));
```

Note: using the {} allows you to qualify your search for uniqueness where similar values exist.

Example: If values were stored as "person|personal|personage" searching for "person" would return a document that has any one of person, personal or personage. By qualifying in curly brackets like so: "{person}|{personal}|{personage}", I can search for "{person}" and be sure it won't return false positives. Of course, this assumes you don't use curly brackets in your values.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Can you explain further what you mean by the {} characters? Is this just for searching or for storing field data as well (as you are doing)?

Comment: Updated with a bit more detail on curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking about [payloads](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/).

Edit: From your use case, it sounds like you have no desire to use this metadata in your search, you just want it there. (Basically, you want to use Lucene as a database system.)

So, why can't you use a binary field?

```
ExtraData ed = new ExtraData { Tag = "tag", Type = "personal" };
byte[] byteData = BinaryFormatter.Serialize(ed); // this isn't the correct code, but you get the point
doc.Add(new Field("myData", byteData, Field.Store.YES));
```

Then you can deserialize it on retrieval.

Comment: That seems more useful for weightings as Grant was using it for. I could see how you could expand it to tag pieces of your data, but it seems more relevant for special handling within a field itself (ie "Text Data" -> "Text|10 Data|5" - adding different weights. In this case, I think he wants something like "Text Data"|GUID - so that GUID refers to the entire field, not pieces of the field, and not to the whole document

Comment: I skimmed that page briefly, but payloads seem *way* too complicated for what I need. It appears I would have to write a completely custom analyzer and generate token streams manually.

Comment: I'm curious about these boosts, though... would it be possible to segment the string value of a field such that I could attach metatdata and assign it a boost of 0 so that it would be ignored by queries? Is this supported by the standard analyzer or would I have to use another/write my own?

Comment: @chaiguy: I've edited my answer: is this more of what you're looking for?

Comment: You're correct in that I have no desire to use the metadata in a search, but I *do* want to be able to use the field's value (e.g. the tag) in a search. I've updated the question with another approach.

Comment: @chaiguy: Why can't you just have one field for searching and one for this metadata?

Comment: I could, if I can be sure the indexes will match up and not change on me, as per my new approach.

Comment: @chaiguy: you can store whatever you want in a binary field, e.g. a hash table. You can be sure that this won't change.