# Is the order of multi-valued fields in Lucene stable?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Suppose I add several values to a `Document` under the same field name:

```
doc.Add( new Field( "tag", "one" ) );
doc.Add( new Field( "tag", "two" ) );
doc.Add( new Field( "tag", "three" ) );
doc.Add( new Field( "tag", "four" ) );
```

If I then later retrieve these fields from a new instance of `Document` (from a search result), am I guaranteed that the order of the `Field`s in the array will remain the same?

```
Field[] fields = doc.GetFields( "tag" );

Debug.Assert( fields[0].StringValue() == "one" );
Debug.Assert( fields[1].StringValue() == "two" );
Debug.Assert( fields[2].StringValue() == "three" );
Debug.Assert( fields[3].StringValue() == "four" );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current code does, but states no guarantees whatsoever, so it may change at any time.

I wouldn't depend on it.

Comment: Hmm, well it's all I have to go on right now, so I may have to. I won't update the Lucene engine without making sure it is still so.