# Lucene - Search for multiple associated values

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I would like to index and search pieces of data that are indexed using Lucene.

**E.g. Items and their colour**

```
Item 1 - Black
Item 2 - Yellow
Item 3 - Red
```

**Search examples**

Search word - `Item`

```
Item 1 - Black
Item 2 - Yellow
Item 3 - Red
```

Search word - `Item 1`

```
Item 1 - Black
```

Search word - `Item 2 - Yellow`

```
Item 2 - Yellow
```

**Possible solution**

From what I found on the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947649/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-metadata-to-a-lucene-field) apparently I can add these into a field using this format.

```
// {Item 1}|{Black}
document.add(new StringField("item", MessageFormat.format("'{'{0}'}'|'{'{1}'}'", itemName, itemColour, Field.Store.YES));
```

If I now do a search with the data in this format I get no results.

I'm using the `StandardAnalyzer`.

This is how I'm creating the query.

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("item", analyzer);
queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query query = queryParser.parse(keyword);
```

I would like to search for:

1. All items that have a matching name
2. All items that match and also have a specific colour

What is the best method of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different structure for the documents in case if you wanna build other possible searches in the future. Here an abstract view

```
new StringField("number", number);
new StringField("item", item);
new StringField("color", color);
```

additional to this 3 fields you add a field for fulltext searches including all the informations of the three fields. This will be done by `TextField` [See Lucene Field javadoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html)

```
new TextField("fulltext", item + " " + number + " " + "color");
```

With this you're able to apply your fulltext search to the "fulltext" field and may some other searches to the other fields directly.

One last thing:

> queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);

You really wanna allow this? this may has performance-impacts and may lead to unexpected search behavior.